# How do you run your Java EE integrated tests? Plus terminology confusion (embedded, managed, local, remote, ...)

Tags: jakarta-ee, testing, integration

I'm trying to set up integrated testing for my simple Java EE app that uses JAX-RS to expose a REST service (it's also an EJB) and JPA to store the underlying data, and I continue to struggle finding a solution that doesn't require manually setting up an external container/application server. I've done a lot of searching here and on the web for solutions, and ended up burning far too many weeks to get GlassFish 3.1.2 Embedded working, which I succeed doing until the final straw a week ago: conflicting documentation and bugs trying to create users to test security. Drat! I looked at JBoss AS 7, but the embedded product looks unsupported. I then tried rolling my own using a servlet container (Jetty, Grizzly, and Simple) to directly run Jersey. (I was eventually planning on adding in EclipseLink and Derby embedded.) All of these presented unexpected and blocking challenges in setting up and running the most basic JUnit tests; I couldn't get Jetty to run JAX-RS, and Grizzly didn't have HTTP Basic authentication, for example. Double drat! I then looked at Arquillian, but couldn't find JBoss AS 7 listed in their container adapters.

I have two questions: 1) This seems to be far, far harder to get working than I expected. If I assume it's not just me (please, it's not just me!), then why is it so hard? I'm wondering if the entire Java EE stack with its 30+ APIs is a house of cards that's very difficult to get stacked up right and doesn't lend itself to being shoved into a single jar. Or maybe people prefer to do integration testing on an external ("local"?) container that they start before running the tests.

Question 2): What is the standard terminology for the different kinds of test-container configurations? It seems inconsistent. For example, http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian.container lists "remote", "embedded", "managed", and "local", but yet I found "in-container" and "out-of-container" testing mentioned elsewhere.

Rather than use space on details on what failed above, I'm ready to listen to what this experience is trying to tell me, so I would really appreciate hearing what worked for you. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problems daily. My conclusion is: decouple the business layer from the service interface layer. i.e.: unit test by doing a good desing of the business layer, and do integration tests with an external tool, if needed (e.g. jmeter or anything that can do functional tests on a deployed system).

Most of the times, I want to test the business logic, not the service abstraction layer. My jax-rs (or whatever) handlers are often just wrappers to the business layer.

I never used Arquillian by the way.

I don't know if this can be considered an answer, it's just my 2 cents ;)

Comment: Thanks, TrustNoOne. I understand designing so that the business logic is separate. In my case I'm asking about the integration/end-to-end correctness. For example, doing a PUT via HTTP to a resource protected with RolesAllowed should fail if the calling credentials are incorrect. In cases like this I need the container to inject @SecurityContext, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do sounds like something I've been doing for some time now.

I'm currently using [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) running with JBoss AS 7, as this is the application server we are using in production. Arquillian supports managed mode (Arquillian is in control of starting and stopping the container), remote mode (Arquillian does not start or stop the server but assumes it is running somewhere) and embedded mode. Not all container adapters support the embedded mode and what I've understood Glassfish embedded has its fair share of problems. Apache TomEE provides an embedded container which I've used in a variety of contexts and it works very well. A good thing with the TomEE adapter is that it is maintained by the actual TomEE team, so they can make sure the adapter is always compliant with their container. TomEE is very fast in its startup/shutdown so the tests are basically as fast as unit tests, the difference is barely noticable. If you are using Maven, use following dependency for Apache TomEE embedded:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The JBoss AS 7 uses Arquillian itself in its test suite, so you don't need to worry about the Java EE API and implementation not being tested for that container. If you want your build to be self-contained and contain a JBoss AS 7 instance, you can use the jboss-as-dist artifact. If you're using Maven you can use the maven-dependency-plugin to unpack a JBoss AS 7 instance to use for your test suite:

```
<build>
  <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <id>unpack</id>
              <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>unpack</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                  <artifactItems>
                      <artifactItem>
                          <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                          <artifactId>jboss-as-dist</artifactId>
                          <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                          <type>zip</type>
                          <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                          <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                      </artifactItem>
                  </artifactItems>
              </configuration>
          </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
</build>
```

(full example pom.xml [here](https://github.com/tommysdk/showcase/blob/master/async-javaee6/pom.xml))

If your code is running inside an application server in production, but you are not integration testing, you really can't be sure how your code will behave in your actual runtime. Thanks to Arquillian, I've been able to write integration tests in my recent projects, which are executed within the application server, testing everything from JAX-RS endpoints over http, JPA ORM-mappings and queries and even business logic towards NoSQL databases and index engines.

The [Arquillian user forums](https://community.jboss.org/en/arquillian?view=discussions) can be a great help if you run in to problems with Arquillian. Hopefully my answer can shed some light on your questions.